# A question about Hecke operators: proving modularity

Tags: modular-forms

So I found an explicit form of the Hecke operators at https://youtu.be/lMD556X4cW4 which is
$$T_p f(\tau)  =p^{k-1} f(p\tau )+\dfrac 1p\sum_{b=0} ^{p-1} f\left(\dfrac {\tau+b} p\right)   $$

The lecturer claims that
$$T_pf\left(-\frac 1\tau\right)=\tau^k T_pf(\tau)  $$
which I had difficulty proving.
($f$ is a modular form of weight $k$.)

I understand it when he said
$$f\left(-\frac p\tau\right)=\left(\frac \tau p\right) ^kf\left(\frac \tau p\right)  $$

where $(k-1) $ factors of $p$ cancels with the $p^{k-1} $.

However I am stuck at
$$f\left(\dfrac{-\frac 1\tau+b} p\right) $$ which leads me nowhere. He mentioned some $b'\in\mathbb Z_p$ such that $bb'\equiv-1 \mod p$ but I do not get how it helps.

For $b=0$ this is easy, since
$$f\left(-\frac 1{\tau p} \right) = (\tau p) ^k f(\tau p) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A_n = \{ M\in M_2(Z),\det(M)=n\}$ $$A_n = \bigcup_{j=1}^J SL_2(Z) b_j $$
disjoint union and the cosets $SL_2(Z) b_j $ are unique.

For $f\in M_k(SL_2(Z))$ the Hecke operator
$$T_n f = \sum_{j=1}^J f|_k SL_2(Z) b_j$$

For $\gamma\in SL_2(Z)$ $$\bigcup_{j=1}^J SL_2(Z) b_j \gamma= A_n \gamma = A_n$$ it means that $ SL_2(Z) b_j \gamma=SL_2(Z) b_{\sigma(j)} $ for some permutation $\sigma$ of the indices.

From there we are done

$$T_n f|_k \gamma = \sum_{j=1}^J f|_k SL_2(Z) b_j \gamma=\sum_{j=1}^J f|_k SL_2(Z) b_{\sigma(j)}=T_n f $$

Your $bb'\equiv-1 \mod p$ question is to find $\sigma$ explicitly, as you see you don't need it.

Comment: I do not understand your answer at all. So is $n=p$? Or is $p=J$?

Comment: But why is your form of Hecke operator equivalent to mine? Can anybody help.....

Comment: I think I start to get your answer, but I do not think that answers my question, so I voted down.

Comment: Very funny. Your question is proving the modularity of $T_p f$ which I did.